# How to Resolve Could not delete path Error?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing Following Error in Android Studio when Run the Application.

Could not delete path /build/debug/0 .How to Resolve this?

Comment: your Os ........????

Comment: clean and rebuild the project

Comment: hey i had already clean and delete directory also.

Comment: delete build folder, don't worry its safe to delete

Comment: Already Delete my build Directory it show repeatedly..

Comment: Windows7 its my OS

Comment: close your androidStudio then delete the folder

Comment: my all projects have a same error when run the project

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for some time. all i did was disabling the "Instant Run" and after some time it magically went away.

Comment: My Instant Run is Always Disabling in my android studio

Comment: what is your android studio and gradle version

Comment: my Gradle version is 4.4 and my android studio is 3.1.3